# Doctrine MongoDB delete reference only onRemove

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, cascade, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

I have a OneToMany Relationship between a ChartPage and a BaseChart:

`1 ChartPage holds 1 BaseChart` and `1 BaseChart holds many ChartPages`

Charts are managed in a different bundle of my application, so they can be removed individually. What I like to have is, that Doctrine automatically removes the ChartPage.Chart reference when the Chart is deleted, but nothing else (**not** remove the ChartPage).

The other way around should leave everything as is: When I remove the ChartPage with a referenced BaseChart - nothing should happen (**not** delete the BaseChart)

I tried every combination with one of these: `cascade="{detach,merge,refresh,remove,persist}"` that I could think of, but I can't figure it out..

This is my mapping:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class ChartPage
 * @package VBCMS\Bundle\AdminBundle\Document\Page
 * @Serializer\AccessType("public_method")
 * @MongoDB\Document()
 */
class ChartPage extends BasePage {

  /**
   * @var BaseChart
   * @Serializer\Type("VBCMS\Bundle\StatisticBundle\Document\BaseChart")
   * @Serializer\Accessor(setter="setChartDeserialize")
   * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(
   *  targetDocument="VBCMS\Bundle\StatisticBundle\Document\BaseChart",
   *  mappedBy="pages",
   *  cascade={"persist,detach,merge"}
   * )
   */
  protected $chart;

}
```

/

```
/**
 * Class BaseChart
 * @package VBCMS\Bundle\StatisticBundle\Document
 * @Serializer\AccessType("public_method")
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *  collection="Chart",
 *  repositoryClass="VBCMS\Bundle\StatisticBundle\Repository\ChartRepository"
 * )
 */
class BaseChart {

  /**
   * @var BasePage[]|Collection
   * @Serializer\Exclude()
   * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
   *   targetDocument="VBCMS\Bundle\AdminBundle\Document\Page\ChartPage",
   *   inversedBy="chart",
   *   cascade={"persist,detach,merge"}
   * )
   */
  protected $pages;

}
```

The only idea I have left is to build a custom preRemove EventListener that sets the references back to `NULL` before a BasePage ist removed, but I hoped I could avoid this manual mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine MongoDB ODM's cascade functionality only operates in one direction. If you perform some lifecycle event on object A, which has a reference to B, we could cascade the persist/remove/etc over to B. There is a concept of orphan removal in ODM, which allows for automated removal of objects embedded or referenced in a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship. I don't believe it's documented in the ODM manual, but it's very similar to what is described in the [ORM documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) for the feature.

In your case, you don't want any cascading functionality on removal of A; you want B to remain as-is.

On the flip side, you *would* like all references to B among A objects to be cleaned up when you manually remove a B object. Using a pre or postRemove listener is your best option for this, and provided you have indexed the reference on A, it should be a very trivial multi-update query to set the references to `null` where they once referred to the instance of B that is removed.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the OrphanRemoval - I wasn't aware of it (due the missing documentation) - I will check it.right now I have implemented a preRemove listener and clear up all my references manually

Comment: The orphan removal option still only applies in the A-to-B direction, so it doesn't seem relevant to your case. You want A.b references to be set to null when B objects are removed on their own. The orphan removal would just remove B objects if the references (on an A) were removed (either single references or from a has-many collection). The preRemove listener does seem appropriate for your needs.